# Ruby net/imap getting OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError - self-signed certificate?

Tags: ruby, ssl, imap, gmail-imap

In trying to develop a tool for that would use IMAP to access Gmail, I'm running into difficulties with even this simple start-up code:

```rb
require 'net/imap'
imap = Net::IMAP.new('imap.gmail.com', ssl: true)
```

Running that, it fails as follows *(Note: lightly edited for easier display)*:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        5: from test-imap:2:in `<main>'
        4: from test-imap:2:in `new'
        3: from /.../.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/imap.rb:1092:in `initialize'
        2: from /.../.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/imap.rb:1533:in `start_tls_session'
        1: from /.../.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/protocol.rb:44:in `ssl_socket_connect'
/.../.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/protocol.rb:44:in
  `connect_nonblock': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error:
  certificate verify failed (self signed certificate) (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
```

Searching around, I found some somewhat-similar issues, e.g. [imap-backup issue #57](https://github.com/joeyates/imap-backup/issues/57), [ruby/openssl issue #238](https://github.com/ruby/openssl/issues/238) (<del>still open, as of this writing</del> closed after sharing the answer below), and [rbenv/ruby-build issue #380](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/issues/380)... but nothing on SO.

Piecing info from the above resources together, I came up with this command to try:

```sh
openssl s_client -connect imap.gmail.com:993 \
  -CAfile $(ruby -ropenssl -e 'puts OpenSSL::X509::DEFAULT_CERT_FILE') \
  < /dev/null > /dev/null
```

Which reports:

```
depth=2 /OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R2/O=GlobalSign/CN=GlobalSign
verify return:1
depth=1 /C=US/O=Google Trust Services/CN=Google Internet Authority G3
verify return:1
depth=0 /C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google LLC/CN=imap.gmail.com
verify return:1
DONE
```

So, it seems that the SSL certificate does actually verify as OK in that way (as one might expect).

I did find [some instructions](https://www.ombulabs.com/blog/ruby/imap/a-comprehensive-guide-to-interacting-with-imap-using-ruby.html) for using `net/imap` with SSL with host-checking disabled, which works... but I'd really prefer not to do that.

I also found a [non-IMAP gmail interface](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/ruby), but my intention is a tool that could also be used with other IMAP providers, so I'm specifically aiming to stick to IMAP here.  So:

How can I get `net/imap` to connect successfully using SSL, and still validate the certificate (given that it is, in fact, valid)?

Answer (score 6):

## Ideal: upgrade to Ruby 2.6.3 or later

Upgrading to Ruby version 2.6.3 or later should fix things, as [ruby pull #2077](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/pull/2077), which provides a fix for [related issue #15594](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/15594), was incorporated into the [2.6.3 change list](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/compare/v2_6_2...v2_6_3).  With 2.6.3, the original test snippet in the question now works.

## If you can't upgrade:

That said, if upgrading is impractical for some reason, the [commit that fixed imap-backup issue #57](https://github.com/joeyates/imap-backup/commit/451634fbba40bf30d2bd7c4c1c2b5b813077f6eb) offers a workaround-type solution.  Instead of the following:

```rb
imap = Net::IMAP.new('imap.gmail.com', ssl: true)
```

Try this:

```rb
imap = Net::IMAP.new('imap.gmail.com', ssl: {ssl_version: :TLSv1_2})
```

That seems to make things work, even in Ruby 2.6.0.

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby 2.4, I had to use this patch:

```rb
require 'net/imap'

class Net::IMAP
  module UseSNI
    def start_tls_session(*)
      @sock.instance_variable_set(:@hostname, @host)
      super
    end
  end

  prepend UseSNI
end

class OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket
  module UseSNI
    def connect(*)
      self.hostname = io.instance_variable_get(:@hostname)
      super
    end
  end

  prepend UseSNI
end
```